Triggering an Automation off an email send
I currently have an automation job set to run every hour to consolidate email tracking data to send to AEP. Im curious if instead of an hourly batch, is it possible to trigger the automation when an email sends from SFMC? Also, is it possible to only include the tracking data of the email sent instead of all email data. Thanks!

This sound like something which could potentially blow up your instance, as consolidation of engagement data is normally performance heavy SQL. Imagine triggering this every second if you are sending multiple emails in batches. To me this sounds like an XY problem. Please update your question describing your ultimate goal of this approach, as there might be another more suitable method for getting there.

Hey Lukas, yes I agree I am trying to avoid sending all email engagement data to AEP every hour. Instead I would like to only send email engagement data to AEP on a per send basis, so instead of sending all engagement data, it would only send it to AEP if an email campaign was sent from SFMC.

I see your point. But engagement data like opens, clicks and bounces can arrive in SFMC at any point in time. If you only sync engagement to AEP (I’m not sure exactly what hides behind this acronym) when emails are sent, you might miss out on a lot of events in the time between sendouts.

That's a good point. AEP stands for Adobe Experience Platform.

None of the SFMC web services (aside from ENS) are built for bulk data operations.  A formal Tracking Extract zip file extract is the tried-and-true method.

@AdamSpriggs I just created and tested a Tracking Extract automation and that worked pretty well. Do you know what the difference would be between running a Tracking Extract automation vs 4 separate automations to gather opens, clicks, bounces, and unsubs? It seems once the files are in Adobe Experience Platform, the ingest method would be the same by creating different data flows per extract file.
